# Ruby Big Decimal Rounding with fixed number

Tags: ruby, rounding

I want to round a `BigDecimal` in ruby. I know I can use the round function but

the round function gives

```
(3.2).round(2) =>  3.2
```

I want

```
(3.2).round(2) =>  3.20
(3.20).round(2) =>  3.20
(3).round(2) =>  3.00
(3.578).round(2) =>  3.58
```

I always want to have 2 decimal places, 3.20 not 3.2

any idea how to get this done ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
'%.2f' % 3.2
=> "3.20"

'%.2f' % 3
=> "3.00"

'%.2f' % 3.578
=> "3.58"

etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

Unlike, for example, [Java's BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), [Ruby's BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) does not have a per-instance precision. The difference between 3.2 and 3.20 in a Ruby BigDecimal is just formatting.

Comment: I don't know any Java so I'm probably misunderstanding. But in some cases specifying a precision for a BigDecimal instance is obligatory in Ruby: `require 'bigdecimal'; BigDecimal.new(1/3.0)` Error: can't omit precision for a Rational.

Comment: True, but that number of significant digits is just used for getting the initial value. It isn't "locked in" to that instance. `require 'bigdecimal'; dec = BigDecimal.new(2.345, 2); dec.precs # => [18, 36]` and `dec.to_s('F') # => "2.3"`